# re-implement __eq__ to compare sets with symmetric_difference in python

Tags: python, set

I have a set of filenames coming from two different directories.

```
currList=set(['pathA/file1', 'pathA/file2', 'pathB/file3', etc.])
```

My code is processing the files, and need to change currList
by comparing it to its content at the former iteration, say processLst.
For that, I compute a symmetric difference:

```
toProcess=set(currList).symmetric_difference(set(processList))
```

Actually, I need the symmetric_difference to operate on the basename (file1...) not
on the complete filename (pathA/file1).

I guess I need to reimplement the `__eq__` operator, but I have no clue how to do that in python.

1. is reimplementing `__eq__` the right approach?
   or
2. is there another better/equivalent approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the magic of generator expressions.

```
def basename(x):
    return x.split("/")[-1]

result = set(x for x in set(currList).union(set(processList)) if (basename(x) in [basename(y) for y in currList]) != (basename(x) in [basename(y) for y in processList]))
```

should do the trick. It gives you all the elements X that appear in one list or the other, and whose basename-presence in the two lists is not the same.

*Edit:*
Running this with:

```
currList=set(['pathA/file1', 'pathA/file2', 'pathB/file3'])
processList=set(['pathA/file1', 'pathA/file9', 'pathA/file3'])
```

returns:

```
set(['pathA/file2', 'pathA/file9'])
```

which would appear to be correct.

Comment: Very pythonic indeed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need the explicit `set` in the argument to `union`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a token (and likely poorly constructed) `itertools` version that should run a little bit faster if speed ever becomes a concern (although agree that @Zarkonnen's one-liner is pretty sweet, so +1 there :) ).

```
from itertools import ifilter

currList = set(['pathA/file1', 'pathA/file2', 'pathB/file3'])
processList=set(['pathA/file1', 'pathA/file9', 'pathA/file3'])

# This can also be a lambda inside the map functions - the speed stays the same
def FileName(f):
  return f.split('/')[-1]

# diff will be a set of filenames with no path that will be checked during
# the ifilter process
curr = map(FileName, list(currList))
process = map(FileName, list(processList))
diff = set(curr).symmetric_difference(set(process))

# This filters out any elements from the symmetric difference of the two sets
# where the filename is not in the diff set
results = set(ifilter(lambda x: x.split('/')[-1] in diff,
              currList.symmetric_difference(processList)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I was looking for something this way before Zarkonnen came with his one-liner. The advantage here is to be able to port it to another language.

Comment: @BrunovonParis No problem, and I agree that Zarkonnen's answer is more easily ported to other languages. Good luck!

Comment: hum, well I think your's is more portable (I think it easily translate to C++ for example). Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @BrunovonParis Ah, gotcha - forgot that other languages probably have some of those capabilities as well :) In any case, glad you found something that works!